# Comparing the exactness of $(\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}M_{\lambda})$ and $M_{\lambda}$ on a long exact sequence.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, injective-module

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $S=\text{End}_R(M), {}_{S}M_R$ be an $(S,R)$-bimodule and $\{M_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ be a family of modules.  Define the map $\phi:M\to M,\phi(m)= mr,r\in R)$ to be an endomorphism of $M$ for every $m\in M$.

**Question (1):**  If the sequence 
$M_{\lambda}\stackrel{\cdot r}{\longrightarrow}M_{\lambda}\stackrel{\gamma}{\longrightarrow}N\longrightarrow0$ is exact for some $\gamma$, then show that the sequence 
$(\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}M_{\lambda})\stackrel{\cdot r}{\longrightarrow}(\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}M_{\lambda})\stackrel{\theta}{\longrightarrow}L\longrightarrow0$ is also exact for some $\theta\in \text{End}_R(M)$.

**Question (2):** Does the converse hold true?  That is, 
if $ (\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}M_{\lambda})\stackrel{\cdot r}{\longrightarrow}(\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda}M_{\lambda})\stackrel{\gamma}{\longrightarrow}L\longrightarrow0$ is exact for some $\gamma$, does that mean that 
$M_{\lambda}\stackrel{\cdot r}{\longrightarrow}M_{\lambda}\stackrel{\theta}{\longrightarrow}N\longrightarrow0$ is exact for some $\theta$?